# Kivy-ios Xcode 14 build error - ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function

Tags: python, kivy, xcode14

I recently upgrade to Xcode 14.2. When I compile my kivy app in Xcode launching simulator iphone 14, I had `ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function`. It pointed to kivy_event. Below are some my error and setting. Is it because of Kivy and Python version's compatibility issue? How I install kivy-ios was using below. Please help.

```
git clone https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios.git
```

kivy 2.2.0, python 3.10.10

```
2023-06-23 23:06:45.874539+1000 myappname[89840:3192006] Available orientation: KIVY_ORIENTATION=Portrait
2023-06-23 23:06:45.874682+1000 myappname[89840:3192006] Initializing python
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib and slated for removal in Python 3.12; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
2023-06-23 23:06:46.043803+1000 myappname[89840:3192006] Running main.py: /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D942FE25-9538-4E1C-993C-9905F9B4E7EC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/ABCEC6A7-2BCA-4E5F-A077-D1631BAEC3AD/myappname.app/YourApp/main.pyc
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D942FE25-9538-4E1C-993C-9905F9B4E7EC/data/Containers/Data/Application/E0192F8C-4FE3-49D1-9459-17501C810541/Documents/.kivy/logs/kivy_23-06-23_1.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.2.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D942FE25-9538-4E1C-993C-9905F9B4E7EC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/ABCEC6A7-2BCA-4E5F-A077-D1631BAEC3AD/myappname.app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.10.10 (main, Jun 21 2023, 13:10:16) [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D942FE25-9538-4E1C-993C-9905F9B4E7EC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/ABCEC6A7-2BCA-4E5F-A077-D1631BAEC3AD/myappname.app/myappname"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 45, in load_module
   File "/Users/xxxx/myappnameApp/kivy-ios/dist/root/python3/lib/python3.10/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 719, in _load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 674, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1176, in create_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
 ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_kivy__event)
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/xxxx/myappnameApp/kivy-ios/myappname-ios/YourApp/main.py", line 1, in <module>
   File "/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D942FE25-9538-4E1C-993C-9905F9B4E7EC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/ABCEC6A7-2BCA-4E5F-A077-D1631BAEC3AD/myappname.app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kivy/uix/screenmanager.py", line 195, in <module>
     from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
   File "/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D942FE25-9538-4E1C-993C-9905F9B4E7EC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/ABCEC6A7-2BCA-4E5F-A077-D1631BAEC3AD/myappname.app/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kivy/event.py", line 8, in <module>
     import kivy._event
   File "<string>", line 49, in load_module
   File "/Users/xxxx/myappnameApp/kivy-ios/dist/root/python3/lib/python3.10/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
 ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__event)
2023-06-23 23:06:46.220093+1000 myappname[89840:3192006] Application quit abnormally!
2023-06-23 23:06:46.232625+1000 myappname[89840:3192006] Leaving
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this error. I think the error was contributed by two factors.

1. I have both python3.9 and 3.10 in my mac, and the 3.9 is default. When I ran toolchain build python3 for kivy-ios, python3.10 was built as the app interpreter. It caused some conflicts. What I did was completely removing reference in my MAC for any python3.9. And I also didn't use any venv when I built kivy and python3 using toolchain.
2. Another factor is that as my app was developed a couple of years ago, some modules are not compatible with python 3.10. I had to recreate a brand new kivy project and ported my core code to that, to avoid unnecessary incompatibility issue.

After I did those two, I was able to run on both simulators and local iphone.

The command I ran when building kivy-ios are:

```
git clone https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios.git
cd kivy-ios/
pip install -e .
toolchain build python3 kivy
toolchain pip install kivymd
```